# Eclipse RCP fireSelectionChanged from Non-SWT client

Tags: eclipse-rcp, osgi

I have the following problem:
I have a framework in which arbitrary clients can run. Imagine you have a non-swt/non-swing client and you want to invoke a fireselectionchanged event to the Workbench. Is that possible somehow. 
Once again. I am not able to get the edior/viewer or something else in my plugin!

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

At any given time there can be only one [selection provider](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ISelectionProvider.html) per workbench window/page and it's the one provided by active [workbench part](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPart.html). Hence, it's only possible to provide selection and notify selection change from a view or an editor.

While it is possible to access the selection provider of current active part and set selection to it...

```
workbenchWindow.getActivePage().getActivePart().getSite().
    getSelectionProvider().setSelection(ISelection);
```

...it's not guaranteed that (1) there is an active part at the time and that (2) the selection provider of the active part supports the type of selection that you want to provide.